# How to use OpenCV trackbars to independently adjust BGR channels without resetting previous changes

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a question about creating multiple trackbars in OpenCV. Here's the code I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void Blue_call(int pos, void* data)
{
  Mat* point = (Mat*)data;
  Mat temp = (*point).clone();
  temp = temp + Scalar(pos, 0, 0);
  imshow("show", temp);
}
void Green_call(int pos, void* data)
{
  Mat* point = (Mat*)data;
  Mat temp = (*point).clone();
  temp = temp + Scalar(0, pos, 0);
  imshow("show", temp);
}
void Red_call(int pos, void* data)
{
  Mat* point = (Mat*)data;
  Mat temp = (*point).clone();
  temp = temp + Scalar(0, 0, pos);
  imshow("show", temp);
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
  Mat image = imread("E:/CodeProject/cmake_test/opencv.png");
  if (image.empty())
  {
    cout << "image is empty" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  namedWindow("show", WINDOW_FREERATIO);
  createTrackbar("B", "show", 0, 255, Blue_call, (void*)&image);
  createTrackbar("G", "show", 0, 255, Green_call, (void*)&image);
  createTrackbar("R", "show", 0, 255, Red_call, (void*)&image);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm attempting to use the 'B', 'G', and 'R' trackbars to alter the color channels of an image. However, when I initially drag the 'B' trackbar to modify the blue channel and then move the 'G' trackbar to adjust the green channel, the blue channel resets. If I remove the

```
Mat temp = (*point).clone();
temp = temp + Scalar(0, pos, 0);
```

in each callback function and replace it with

```
(*point)=(*point)+Scalar(0,pos,0);
```

the adjusted image overwrites the original image with each change, eventually causing the image to turn white. How can I resolve this issue so that I can modify the BGR values of the image using the three trackbars, similar to how it's done in Photoshop?